# Install worklight project in Blackberry 6-7

Tags: blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I have built a worklight-based app for blackberry phones. I was able to run it on Blackberry 10 by following the instructions given on worklight documents.

Now i want to install my app on Blackberry 6-7. Am not able to find any document for it by IBM. So is there way for me to install my app on Blackberry 6-7? If so please post the steps to install and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention *where* you looked at, so I guess you didn't look close enough because in the same location explained how to set-up and develop for BlackBerry 10 in Worklight, there are also documents for BlackBerry 6 and 7.

Follow the training modules.

- [Setting up your BlackBerry 6 and 7 development environment](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_set)
- [Previewing your application on BlackBerry 6 and 7](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_hello)
- [General information when developing for BlackBerry 6 and 7](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#GS_client_dev)

And in general: [IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html)

Comment: One more query Mr Idan.The UI for Blackberry 6 and Blackberry 10 is totally different.So suppose i want to create an msite environment for Blackberry six .And for that i need to create two msite environment in same worklight project,so is it possible for me to iframe into blackberry 6.If not please suggest me an alternative

Comment: The UI of your app will look the same in both 6 and 10 if you place it in the common folder; please read the training materials, all of them.

Comment: I read the materials you had suggested and tried a sample project in blackberry simulator using webwork SDK.But there is a major issue which am not able to solve .The webwork doesnt seems to call wlCommonInit function and inturn none of the worklight functionality is not working